# Prime Ideals in a Field

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This is probably a really simple question:

Am I right in thinking that a field has only one prime and one maximal ideal, namely the $(0)$ ideal? I think this is so because both prime/maximal ideals cannot have units in them since they are proper ideals and so $(0)$ is the only such ideal which satisfies this criterion?

Comment: yes exactly right.

Comment: A field only has two ideals, the trivial and the whole field.  Only the trivial ideal is prime.

Comment: Moreover: A ring with precisely two ideals is already a field!

Comment: Generally $R/I\,$ is a field $\!\iff \!I$ is maximal in $R.\,$ Yours is the special case $I=0,\,$ since $R/0 \cong R.\ \ $